# Hiding spoiler tagged text in question excerpts

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro, spoilers

I noticed in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156106/why-is-this-weapon-searching-for-a-new-owner) that while the OP used the spoiler tags in the body of the text the question excerpt that appears on the Stack All Questions page includes text from the spoiler.

Is there a way to avoid this/guidance for question writers to start their question with enough non-spoiler text to negate this effect?

Comment: This is not happening to me. Can you include more information? Maybe a screen capture?

Comment: Could you clarify which page you mean by the "Stack All Questions" page?

Comment: ...[Is it this one?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions) If so, as Sdjz says, I can confirm that the spoilered text is not shown to me either - it appears to me as: "In Dragon Heist, Meloon Wardragon wields Azuredge, the legendary greataxe. Players discover that... So... My players have handled that problem with a swift Protection from Evil and Good, but I'm not sure if that was the actual reason, or if it was something else. … ") The spoilered text in the original post is what's between "Players discover that..." and "So..." and between "So..." and "My players have handled that".

Comment: @V2Blast Yes that was the page. I can confirm that it is no longer happening for me. I think that I may have opened the All Questions page before the spoiler tags had been added and then clicked on the question after the tags were added.